# auto disable edit and continue on 64X

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm working with a project which runs on 64X, and have VS2008. 
So for enabling "edit and continue" I'm switching to X86, and enabling the button. The thing is I want an automatic code which will disable/enable the "edit and continue" according to the solution configuration. I'm switching modes many times, and too many times I'm finding my self trying to change the code, and disabled by the debugger.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade to VS2013 for this feature, edit and continue is not supported in earlier version on 64bit:

[debugging-support-for-64-bit-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/debugging-support-for-64-bit-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Comment: I want to auto disable edit and continue if I'm running SW under X64 configs. If I do so - the code isn't read only.